# How to make another laravel passport api guard?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

*I want to make another `api` quard for laravel and I created*

```
<?php
return [
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],


'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'dlp_api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'hash' => false,
    ]
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

*but it not working, the login function works fine and create a token 
but when I use `Route::post('/blog','Api\Blog@store')->middleware('auth:dlp_api');`in a route it redirect me to the login page but if i use '`Route::post('/blog','Api\Blog@store')->middleware('auth:api');`' and change the token it works fine I'm currently using postman for requesting*